# Meaning of sink in the following sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of sink in the following sentence

> Her head ***sinks*** on her shoulder.

Meaning of sink is ***to fall or move to a lower level***

Does this mean her head fell on her shoulder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it means "lower the head, quite slowly, so it rests on the shoulder".  This is figurative language.

It's not certain from the short quote if the word "her" refers to the same person or to two different people. You could sink your head onto your own shoulder when you are tired. You could sink your head onto someone else's shoulder as a sign of love or affection.